# Change the inner html of selected element using jQuery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap navtabs

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs shorttabs" id="homeTabs">
                        <li data-have="Pictures" class="active"><a href="#pictures">Inspiring Pictures</a></li>
                        <li data-have="Videos"><a href="#videos">Videos</a></li>
                        <li data-have="Quotes"><a href="#quotes">Quotes</a></li>
                        <li data-have="People"><a href="#people">People</a></li>
                        <li data-have="Books"><a href="#books">Books</a></li>
                        <li data-have="Messages"><a href="#books">Messages</a></li>

                      </ul>
```

Each li element have  element that has displays like "Video", "Quotes" etc.

when every li element becomes active when clicked, i wish to append "Inspiring" word before what text that is actually there,

example 
if "Videos" is actual text, then when the user hovers on the tab, it should show "Inspiring Videos", when clicked the word "Inspiring videos" should stay, any previously added inspiring should get removed.

I am trying with jquery code, but i can't get through without affecting orignial tab functionality

```
$(".shorttabs li").on("click", function(){
    var test = $(this).html
    console.log(test);

    });
```

The original tab functionlity is selected with seperate selector `$("#homeTabs").nav()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do this:

```
$(".shorttabs li a").on("click", function () {
    $this = $(this).text();
    // alert($this);
    $(".shorttabs li a").each(function () {
        //alert($(this).text());
        if ($(this).text() == $this) {
            if ($(this).text().indexOf("Inspiring") < 0) {
                $(this).text("Inspiring" + $(this).text());
            }
        } else {
            $(this).text($(this).text().replace("Inspiring", ""));
        }
    });
});
```

[Working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qmqb6/3/)

Comment: Your code works, but it adds "inspiring" number of times the link is clicked. The previously added inspiring should be removed in order to fix this error.

Comment: That worked leaving behind the tab functionality un .altered. Thanks

Comment: But, click the same link twice, It appends on the text again and again. this should not be the case, How to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Just change text of hyperlink

```
$(".shorttabs li a").on("click", function(){
    // Remove inspiring from all anchors
    $(".shorttabs li a").each(function(){
        $(this).text($(this).text().replace("inspiring",""));
    });

    // Add to current one 
    $(this).text("inspiring" + $(this).text);

 });
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/qmqb6/)

Comment: The original tab functionality breaks, when replacing with "text.replace". I get console error  "has no method 'replace'". However if i remove that line, your code works. But i also working for removing previously added "inspiring". is there any other way you could think of replacing the previously appended "Inspiring"